# How to return 2 variables at the same time in Python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

```py
class Head(App):    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self): 
        SL = StackLayout(orientation ='rl-bt')
        TL = StackLayout(orientation = 'lr-tb')
         
        button1 = Button(text ="1", 
                      font_size = 18, 
                      size_hint =(.30, .1)) 
                      
        button2 = Button(text ="2", 
                      font_size = 18, 
                      size_hint =(.39, .1)) 
                      
        button3 = Button(text ="3", 
                      font_size = 18, 
                      size_hint =(.30, .1))
        button4 = Button(text ="3", 
                      font_size =18, 
                      size_hint =(.30, .1))
         
        SL.add_widget(button1) 
        SL.add_widget(button2)
        SL.add_widget(button3)
        TL.add_widget(button4)


        #problem is here
        return SL
        return TL
        #problem is here
        
root = Head()
root.run()
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `kivy`. Does your `build()` method need to return two variables? Did you try: `return SL, TL`?

Comment: I tried return SL, TL it didn't work

Comment: why do you need two objects? GUI may have only one main object. And if you need to display to objects then put both in one widget which will work as main object.

Comment: I'm sorry, but `"it didn't work "` isn't a description of the problem. How do you know it didn't work? Why do you need two variables and why do you need to return them?

Comment: if you need to return two objects then you need `return SL, TL` and `SL, TL = Head()` but later you have to decide if you will run `SL.run()` or `TL.run()` because `GUI` may run only one main object (main window, main application). And if you want to display both then you should put both in other  widget and return this widget.

Comment: @furas: `SL` and `TL` are being returned from the `build()` method. What do you think that `SL, TL = Head()` means?

Comment: Returning two variables should work.  If you had a statement such as "STK = hd.build()", STK would be a tuple.  You could then refer to each element as STK[0] and STK[1].  That should work.

Comment: @quamrana my mistake, I didn't check that it is `build()` and it will return it in some code in `run()` - and `Head()` can return only instance of object (`self`)

Comment: Your `build()` method must return the one and only root widget for your `App`. If you want two `StackLayout` widgets, then you should create another `Layout` that contains those two `StackLayouts`, and return just that containing `Layout`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
    return SL
    return TL
```

with:

```
box = BoxLayout()
box.add_widget(SL)
box.add_widget(TL)
return box
```